# How to intercept a hot key in Cocoa when the application window is not active

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, x86-64, hotkeys

I am trying to create a utility that doesn't open a window when executed, and that would be activated from a hot key; I read that currently Cocoa doesn't have a function for that, and that I should use a deprecated Carbon function.

Isn't there really a way to use global hot keys in Cocoa? What should I do: wait for Cocoa to introduce a function for that, or use  the carbon function until a similar function is not introduced in Cocoa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [the Carbon Event Manager's `RegisterEventHotKey` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/RegisterEventHotKey). **This function is supported in 64-bit** (notice that it lacks the “not available in 64-bit” availability note).

Conversely, NSEvent's new `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` method in Snow Leopard is *not* the easiest way to implement a hot-key. For one thing, it requires that the user have access for assistive devices turned on; moreover, it requires you to examine every event yourself, as compared with the `RegisterEventHotKey` system, which only calls your callback function when the user presses the specific key you registered for.

Comment: I was trying to avoid to use a function for a library that could be declared unsupported from Apple in any moment. As far as I can see, Carbon doesn't seem to get deprecated in the near future, even if Apple always declared that Carbon was only a library to allow the passage to Mac OS X, and that could be removed at any time. <br />
It doesn't make sense to wait for a Cocoa class to handle hot keys, when the class could be introduced between 5 years.

Comment: Apple has never said that. The name "Carbon" was arrived at because of the notion that "all life is based on carbon." Cocoa is a convenience wrapper, not the basis of anything important.

Comment: In typical Apple fashion, they have removed the documentation for the `RegisterEventHotKey` function from their web site. However, at least one sample app ([UIElementInspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html)) still uses it (in [`AppDelegate.m`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Listings/AppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000728-AppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4)), and it's still documented in the `CarbonEvents.h` header file.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Shortcut Recorder (http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/) a framework that uses the Carbon Event Manager for Global Hotkeys it also allows you to change the user to change the HotKey (if this is what you want).

And see this Project/Code on how to implement it : http://github.com/sdegutis/SDGlobalShortcuts.