# OSX Carbon: Quartz event taps to get keyboard input

Tags: macos, keyboard, quartz-graphics, macos-carbon

I want to get Keyboard Input on OSX using c++ without using Cocoa, deprecated Carbon UPP handlers and if possible without using IOHID since that's alot of extra work.
I allready implemented a simple mouse class using quartz event taps and it works like a charm and now I'd like to use them to implement a keyboard class. Anyways as the reference states under **CGEventTapCreate**:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html

you can only access key events if one of the following is true:

1. The current process is running as the root user.
2. Access for assistive devices is enabled. In Mac OS X v10.4, you can
   enable this feature using System Preferences, Universal Access
   panel, Keyboard view.

that is a very serious limitation since I also want my application to work without any weird settings. **Is there any way to work around this?** If not, is there any alternative to using Taps in Carbon?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the semi-deprecated Carbon function `RegisterEventHotKey`, see [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914811/how-to-intercept-a-hot-key-in-cocoa-when-the-application-window-is-not-active), for example.

If not, you need to live with that restriction. The restriction is there to prevent a bad person to install keylogger behind the scenes. You need to ask the user to open the preferences, type the admin password etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [AXMakeProcessTrusted](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1462083-axmakeprocesstrusted). This is supposed to be the same as *Access for assistive devices* on a per process basis.

Comment: hey, that looks great, anyways its a bigger hastle than its worth. I am capturing the key events from cocoa now (inside NSApplication sendEvent function) since I only need the events on an app level anyways. thanks!